# Ajax Autocomplete for Jquery : not able to use methods such as setOptions or disable

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am using Ajax Autocomplete for Jquery (http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/). With version 1.1, you can declare an autocomplete instance as a variable and then use methods such as setOptions, enable, or disable to dynamically alter the autocomplete:

```
var ac = $('#query').autocomplete(options);
ac.disable();
ac.enable();
ac.setOptions({ zIndex: 1001 });
```

This is not working for me in the latest version (1.2.4), and I get the following example error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'disable'`.

I could use the older version, but there is some new functionality in v1.2 I would like to use. Any ideas how to dynamically change the autocomplete options in v1.2? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To disable/enable you need to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
ac.prop('disabled', true);
ac.prop('disabled', false);
```

To set styles you need to use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
ac.css({ zIndex: 1001 });
```